# Run WordCount without reducer in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, jar, mapreduce, reduce

I have installed hadoop cluster environment (Master & Slave). Works smoothly.

I tried wordcount and grep using (hadoop.example.jar) file and also works fine.

Now, I want to edit the (hadoop.example.jar) to run only mapper without reducer. Is there a way on doing that???

I read some articles that says I have to set the value to zero of setNumReducerTask(0), but I don't know how? using the (hadoop.example.jar) file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the hadoop.example.jar file.

You need to create your own custom code and export it as a jar file.

The modified wordcount code should be:

```
package org.myorg;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;

public class WordCount {

public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable {
private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
private Text word = new Text();

public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String line = value.toString();
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
        context.write(word, one);
    }
}
} 

public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) 
  throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    int sum = 0;
    for (IntWritable val : values) {
        sum += val.get();
    }
    context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
}
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
Job job = new Job(conf, "wordcount");

job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
**job.setNumReduceTasks( 0 ); **

job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

job.waitForCompletion(true);
}

}
```

[The origianl source code](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WordCount)